# How to save the last view set by viewSwitcher and restore it when relaunching activity?

Tags: android, setcontentview, viewswitcher

I have an Activity that uses a ViewSwitcher to switch between two views. The `onCreate()` method uses `setContentview()` to set the view to one of the two views.

When leaving the Activity and going back to it again later, I want the view that was shown last to be the one that is picked in the viewSwitcher (not the one in SetContentview every single time).

How would I accomplish this?

I tried something like this, but the app crashes when I try to load the Activity:

```
private View lastState = findViewById(R.id.activity_login_page);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(lastState);
```

Comment: Where are you saving `lastState`?

Comment: The ViewSwitcher switches views in an onClick method for a button in one of the two views. So in that method i have: lastState = findViewById(R.id.Loggedin);

Answer (score 0):

I achieved something similar by using ViewFlipper.

SettingsActivity

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   boolean state;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

       Button right = findViewById(R.id.right);
       Button left = findViewById(R.id.left);
       right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               state = true;
               editor.putBoolean("handstate", state);
               editor.apply();
           }
       });
       left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               state = false;
               editor.putBoolean("handstate", state);
               editor.apply();
           }
       });
   }
```

ViewFlippingActivity

```
public class VIewFlippingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_flipping);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


        ViewFlipper flipper = findViewById(R.id.flipper);
        RelativeLayout layoutRight = findViewById(R.id.layoutRight);
        RelativeLayout layoutLeft = findViewById(R.id.layoutLeft);

        boolean statereceive = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("handstate", false);
        if (statereceive == true) {
            flipper.setDisplayedChild(flipper.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.layoutRight)));
        } else if (statereceive == false){
            flipper.setDisplayedChild(flipper.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.layoutLeft)));
        } else {
            flipper.setDisplayedChild(flipper.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.layoutRight)));
        }
    }
```

viewflipping_activity.xml

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/flipper"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".VIewFlippingActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutRight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:background="@color/royal_android">

          //your content
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutLeft"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:background="@color/royal_blue">
              //your content

    </RelativeLayout>


</ViewFlipper>
```

Sorry for the bad Explanation and difficult to read code im in a hurry.
Hope it still provides some sort of help.